# Windows : Ask Socket to deliver all packets (even the corrupted)

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, udp, winsock

My current job is to analyse the kind of lost in a real time transmission.

The C++ software is made for Windows(using Visual Studio) with a Raw UDP Socket, i use the socket lib winsock2.h.

I just want to ask the socket or the OS, to delivers all the packets even the corrupted/discarded one.

How can i achieve that ?

Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll need to write your own protocol driver for that. Wireshark might be a good starting point.

Comment: I looking for something to modify in the Windows Registry. Or in my Network interface controller .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution

The SIO_RCVALL control code enables a socket to receive all IPv4 or IPv6 packets passing through a network interface.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee309610(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I would like to add that administrative privileges are required to use this control code.